# Replacing shell variable names in another variable

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

I've been wrestling with `bash` variable substitution for a while now and can't figure this out...

I have a variable with a command template:

```
CMD_TMPL='sudo -u ${USER_NAME} ${USER_HOME}/script.sh'
```

The variables `USER_NAME` and `USER_HOME` are figured out later in the script, not yet known at the time `CMD_TMPL` is defined. Therefore the command is in single-quotes and the are not yet substituted.

Then the script figures out `USER_NAME=test` and `USER_HOME=/home/test` and I want to do something that will lead to `${CMD}` containing:

```
sudo -u test /home/test/script.sh
```

Further down in the script I will use that command in a pipe like:

```
${CMD} | output-processing.sh
```

How do I achieve the expansion from variable names in `${CMD_TMPL}` to variable values in `${CMD}`? I tried all sorts of `echo`'s and `eval`'s but can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: You say you've tried `eval` already. Did `eval "$CMD_TMPL"` not work? What went wrong with it?

Comment: Why does `CMD_TMPL` need to be declared prior to `$USER_NAME` and `$USER_HOME`?

Comment: @Warwick - the template is in a header of the file together with other settings. I don't want a hardcoded setting way down buried in the script where it is actually used.

Comment: @MichaelHomer - `eval` doesn't only substitute the variables but also immediately executes the command. That's not what I want - I want the expanded vars assigned to a new variable first. That's a requirement for logging and auditing... I'm sure it should be doable...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a special type of variable that is used to store code, that's *functions*:

```
cmd_tmpl() { sudo -u "$USER_NAME" "$USER_HOME/script.sh" "$@"; }
cmd() { cmd_tmpl other args "$@"; }
cmd | output_processing...
```

The other approaches are to consider the variables as command lines (shell code) and interpret that code in the end using `eval`:

```
cmd_tmpl='sudo -u "$USER_NAME" "$USER_HOME/script.sh"'
cmd=$cmd_tmpl' other args as shell code'
eval "$cmd" | output_processing...
```

Using `$cmd | output_processing` is wrong. `$cmd` is a scalar variables and you're using the split+glob operator to obtain the list of arguments to a simple command, you're not evaluating the command line stored in it. So that only works in a constrained set of conditions.

You can store arguments to a simple command in an array:

```
cmd=(sudo -u "$USER_NAME" "$USER_HOME/script.sh" ...)
"${cmd[@]}" | post_processing
```

but that won't help with the deferred expansion of your variables.

You could defer the expansion though with things like:

```
cmd_tmpl='sudo -u "$USER_NAME" "$USER_HOME/script.sh"'
...
eval "cmd=($cmd_tmpl)" # now expanded
cmd+=(other args)
"${cmd[@]}" | post-processing
```

(note that it's good practice to reserve all-uppercase variable names to variables exported to the environment).